# Camel HeaderFilterStrategy Bean Registration in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, javabeans, spring-camel

I am having difficulty with Spring-Camel getting a HeaderFilterStrategy class registered as a Bean so it can be found by the Camel Route.  My attempts to annotate the HeaderFilterStrategy custom class seem futile... so how do I register this thing so it gets found at run time?

I have a camel application with a route utilizing a custom HeaderFilterStrategy

The Strategy Class looks like :

```
public class HeaderFilter implements HeaderFilterStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilterToCamelHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
      return false;
    }

   @Override
   public boolean applyFilterToExternalHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
    return true;
   }
}
```

I register it with camel using a simple registry:

```
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.put("HeaderFilter" ,new HeaderFilter());
    .
    .
    final CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
```

And I reference it in my Route in

```
.to("https://myhost/endpoint&headerFilterStrategy=#HeaderFilter")
```

And all like Ralphy on Christmas night with his trusty Red Rider BB Gun, all is right with the world.

So, now I am trying to take this pure camel app and put it under Spring.  I make sure all the appropriate Camel, and Spring-Camel and Spring things are imported.. However, when I attempt to annotate my HeaderStrategy as a Bean for Spring and it fails:

```
@Component
public class HeaderFilter implements HeaderFilterStrategy {

@Bean
  @Override
  public boolean applyFilterToCamelHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
    return false;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean applyFilterToExternalHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now when I do this, the IDE basically tells me it can't autowire any of the parameters in the method calls becaue there is more than one bean of type String or Object and no beans of type Exchange found..

At Runtime, Camel does attempt to interpret the route, but throws a failure with "No Qualifying bean type of "java.lang.String" available, since this is the first parameter in the method call...

So, How do I get this thing to be able register with annotations correctly?  Or manually register this bean without it attempting to autowire?   All I need is the class to be registered as a BEAN so it can be found by camel at runtime... Or at least that is what I understand needs to happen... so how the heck to I do this?

Comment: In the Spring way remove `@Bean` annotation from `applyFilterToCamelHeaders` method and replace `#HeaderFilter` with `#headerFilter`. I don't see the reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was not properly using the annotationsI added the following to my AppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{

  @Bean 
  public HeaderFilter HeaderFilter(){
    return new HeaderFilter();
  }
}
```

I am not sure if the suggestion above will work, but this clearly does.